# How to finds the minimal polynomial of $α + α ^2$ over $\Bbb Q$.?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime and $K = \Bbb Q(α)$, where $α ^3 = p$. Find the minimal polynomial of $α + α ^2$ over $\Bbb Q$.

my  attempt : I  was taking  $α + α ^2$=  $α(1 + α )$=$0$ and getting $α =0$ and $α= -1$  as I don't know how to proceed further

Please, Help me.

Comment: If $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^3-p=0$, find a polynomial satisfied by $x = \alpha+\alpha^2$.  Then factor that.

Comment: im not getting @GEdgar

Comment: Just take powers of your expression and look for relations.  If $\beta=\alpha+\alpha^2$ then $\beta^2=\alpha^2+2\alpha^3+\alpha^4=\alpha^2+2p+\alpha p$ and so on.

Comment: For general find-the-minimal-polynomial problems, I address one technique [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230280/find-the-degree-of-extension-bbb-qζ-9-ζ−1-9-over-bbb-q/2230302#2230302) (start reading at "Alternative method" halfway down the post). The downsides of this method include the Galois group not being easily computable or having a mess of radicals to deal with when computing the product of linear factors (they *do* simplify!). If the Galois group is well-understood and if you're content with a CAS like Mathematica doing some multiplication for you, then it's perfect.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088129/minimal-polynomial-of-an-algebraic-number-expressed-in-terms-of-another-algebrai) may be useful.

Comment: thanks  a lots @Quasicoherent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: start with $x=\alpha + \alpha^2\Rightarrow x-\alpha^2=\alpha$ then try to cube it and then try to make the coefficients of the polynomial in $\Bbb Q$.

**Adding details:**

After taking cube $x-\alpha^2=\alpha$ we get $x^3-3\alpha^2x^2+3\alpha^4 x-\alpha^6=\alpha^3=b \Rightarrow x^3-3\alpha^2x^2+3p\alpha x-p^2=b$

Now observe that $x^3-p=0\Rightarrow \big(\frac x {\alpha}\big)^3-1=0\Rightarrow \alpha^2+x\alpha+x^2=0$. Now you take from here.

Comment: im not getting @USer152715  can u elababorate in detail???

Comment: i accepted ur answer @user152715   but still not getting $\alpha^2+x\alpha+x^2=0$.  how  to put this on  above  equation?

Comment: $y^3-1=(x-1)(1+x+x^2)$. Now put $y=x/\alpha$ then clear the denominator.

Comment: thanks  a  lots @User 152715  i got its now

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\p&0&0}$$
has $\alpha$ as an eigenvalue (for eigenvector $\pmatrix{1\\\alpha\\\alpha^2}$). Then $B=A+A^2$ has $\alpha+\alpha^2$ as an eigenvalue,
so that $f(\alpha)=0$ where $f$ is the characteristic polynomial of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

A fully automated way to approach such questions is to use [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) or [Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis). For example in this case the [resultant](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%28x%5E3+-+p%2Cy-%28+x%5E2+%2B+x%29%2C+x%29) of $x^3-p$ and $y - (x^2+x)$ with respect to $x$ turns out to be $y^3 - 3 p y - p^2 - p$ which happens to be irreducible. The same polynomial appears in the [Gröbner basis](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=groebner+basis%5B%7Bx%5E3+-+p%2C+y-%28+x%5E2+%2B+x%29%7D%2C+%7Bx%2Cy%2Cp%7D%5D) of the ideal $(x^3-p, y-(x^2+x))$ with respect to the lexicographical order with $x>y>p$.