# How to show that $x^8 - x^7 + x^5 - x^4 + x^3 - x + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How can I show that $f(x) = x^8 - x^7 + x^5 - x^4 + x^3 - x + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

It's easy to see that $f$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}$ -- so the factorization of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ will involve no linear factors.

But, it gets very tedious to try and show that $f(x)$ does not factor as a quadratic times a sixth degree polynomial, a cubic times a fifth degree polynomial, or the product of two fourth degree polynomials. It's also not promising to try and Eisenstein's Criterion -- even if one makes the substitutions $x \longmapsto x+1$, $x \longmapsto x-1$, or $x \longmapsto x+2$ for example, Eisenstein's Criterion still can't be applied.

Is there a relatively easy way to see why $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that $f(z)$ is the $30$-th cyclotomic polynomial, and they are irreducible (https://www.lehigh.edu/~shw2/c-poly/several_proofs.pdf) (I don't know if there is an easy fact to prove, I just think of it)

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532960/showing-that-nth-cyclotomic-polynomial-phi-nx-is-irreducible-over-mathb) contains a discussion of he irreducibility of cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: Looks rather more to be the fifteenth cyclotomic polynomial, @AleTolcachier .

Comment: @Lubin you're right, I didn't see the signs, Heh.

Comment: @AleTolcachier Thanks. I didn't even think to recognize the polynomial as cyclotomic. That's a great catch. I appreciate your time. (=