# Eisenstein Criterion Example

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How to I use the Eisenstein Criterion to show that for any prime $p$, $1+x^{p}+x^{2p}+...+x^{p(p-1)}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? I tried using the substitution $x = y+1$ and I guess this works but this method seems too complicated. Is there a more efficient/elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We only need Eisenstein to show the irreducibility for the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_p=1+X+X^2+\cdots +X^{p-1}$ over $\Bbb Q$. For prime powers then the usual proof works for showing that $\Phi_n$ is irreducible by considering  $X^n-1=g\Phi_n$ and passing to $\Bbb F_p[X]$. In our case
$$
\Phi_{p^2}=1+X+X^p+\cdots +X^{(p-1)p}.
$$

Comment: How is the last equation related to Phi_n?

Comment: Can you also elaborate when you say passing to F_p[x]? I am having trouble seeing the connection between the last two sentences

Comment: @Dietrich What happened to you dupe searching?  Obviously this is a FAQ (and an easy search).

Comment: @Dietrich Did you find an answer by me?  I didn't answer in the dupe(s) I linked.

Comment: I got lost in too many posts about this topic, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532960/showing-that-nth-cyclotomic-polynomial-phi-nx-is-irreducible-over-mathb?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the links, I am sorry. But I have seen an answer of yours for the general case.

Comment: @Dietrich and BillDubuque Thank you very much. Appreciate it!