# Is $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Is $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$?

I understand that if asked for $\mathbb{Q}$, the answer is yes, because $$f(x) = x^{5-1}+ x^{5-2} + x^{5-3} +x^{5-4} +1.$$

Since $5$ is prime, therefore it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

But can we say that, since it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, it is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$? I am not clear about it.

Comment: Any factorization over $\mathbb Z$ is also a factorization over $\mathbb Q$, so irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ implies irreducible over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: If it was reducible over $\Bbb{Z}$, then wouldn't it be reducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ as well since $\Bbb{Z} \subset \Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: But shouldn't it be opposite?

Comment: Is a polynomial in $\Bbb Z$ also a polynomial in $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Yes. A polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}$ is polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Is this it? Gauss's lemma, is that a primitive polynomial is irreducible over the integers if and only if it is irreducible over the rational numbers.

Comment: I completely forgot that invertible elements of $\mathbb Q[X]$ are not the same as $\mathbb Z[X]$. @JCAA was right, this is the statement of Gauss's lemma.

Comment: Since $\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb Q$, the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb Z$ either

Comment: Another possibility is drawing a picture. If the graph doesn't intersect the $x$-axis there are no real zeros and hence there are CERTAINLY no integer zeros...

Comment: @Vincent: irreducibilty over $\mathbb{Z}$ is not the same as having no integer zeroes.

Comment: O wait, you are right, that only proves it has no linear factors but doesn't rule out that the thing is a produc two degree two irreducible polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.

Another way:

Let $x=y+1$.

Thus, $$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=y^4+5y^3+10y^2+10y+5$$ and use Eisenstein: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion

Comment: We'll only be able to prove it till rationals. We then have to use Gauss lemma as mentioned above, in the end.

Comment: @Muskaan Madan But a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ it's equivalent that it's irreducible over $\mathbb Z$, which gives an answer on your question. I just posted another way to understand that $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z.$

Comment: That's what I said

Comment: +1 Well this is actually one of the ways we prove the irreducibilty of $f(x) =(x^p-1)/(x-1)$ over $\mathbb {Z} $, given $p$ a prime. The irreducibilty of $f$ in $\mathbb{Q} $ then follows from Gauss lemma.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg $2x$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ but not over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @lisyarus But the degree of $2$ is zero. You example is not correct. See please better a definition of a polynomial irreducibility.

Comment: Ah, it never occurred to me that irreducible polynomial and irreducible element of the polynomial ring are different things. You are right.

Comment: Using different definitions for irreducible polynomial and irreducible element of a polynomial ring is weird. Just introduce the notion of a primitive polynomial to bridge the discrepancy and make Gauss lemma work.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$$

$$f(x) = x^{5-1}+ x^{5-2} + x^{5-3} +x^{5-4} +1.$$

Since $5$ is prime, therefore it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

By Gauss's lemma,

A primitive polynomial is irreducible over the integers if and only if it is irreducible over the rational numbers.

Using the lemma above,

Since  $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, therefore,   $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ too.

Comment: Gauss lemma is implication "if $p(x) \in\mathbb {Z} [x] $ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z} $ then it is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Q} $". The converse is a trivial result by inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb {Q} $ and is the topic of your question. I don't see the use of Gauss lemma necessary here.

Comment: So, what's the best way to put it?

Comment: Best way is to use the answer by Michael Rozenberg (using Eisenstein criterion). Another option is to use a more general result of Gauss namely that [cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/532977/72031).