# why $\zeta^p$ is again a primitive $n^{th}$ root of $1$ in theorem $41$ Dummit and foote book?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have some confusion regarding Dummit and foote Book Algebra, page number $554$

> Theorem $41$.The cyclotomic polynomial  $\Phi_n(x)$  is  an irreducible monic polynomialin $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of  degree  $\varphi(n)$

> Proof :   we must  show   that  $\Phi_n(x)$  is irreducible. If not then we have a factorization   $$\Phi_n(x) = f(x)g(x)$$ with  $f(x),g(x)$  monic polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ where  we take $f(x)$ to be an irreducible  factor of $\Phi_n(x)$. let  $\zeta$ to be a primitive $n^{th}$ root of $1$  which is a  root of $f(x)$ (so then $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\zeta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$) and  let $p$ denote any prime not dividing $n$ .**Then  $\zeta^p$ is again  a primitive $n^{th}$ root of $1$**, hence  is   a root of either $f(x)$ or  $g(x)$.

**My confusion** : Im not getting why  $\zeta^p$ is again  a primitive $n^{th}$ root of $1?$

**My thinking** : It is given that   $\zeta$ is a primitive $n^{th}$ root of $1$

That means only  the power $n $ will give $1$ and the remaining power (not equal  to $n$) will not  give unity

So i think $\zeta^p \neq 1$ because $p \neq n$

i,e  $\zeta^p$ is **not** again  a primitive $n^{th}$ root of $1$

Comment: If $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$-th root of $1$ then it's multiplicative order is $n$ and hence $\text {ord} (\zeta^p) = \frac {n} {\text {gcd} (p,n)} = n$ (since $p$ doesn't divide $n$).

Comment: You can observe that $(\zeta^p) ^n=(\zeta^n) ^p=1$ so $\zeta^p$ is an $n$th root of unity. It is primitive because $p\nmid n$ implies that $\zeta ^p=\zeta^k$ where $k$ is remainder when $p$ is divided by $n$ and $k$ is coprime to $n$.

Comment: You may have a look at this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/532977/72031